# Trying to return a value in get function from Realtime Database Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

console.log prints the data but function return promise instead of the specific value, firebase Realtime database.

Tries to return a value of the user but instead receives the Promise.

The function I'm using:

```
const getData=async()=> {
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
    const reference = get(child(dbRef, `users/${user.uid}`))
    
    await reference.then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log("snap",snapshot.val())
            return snapshot.val();
        }
        
    });
}
```

The value I get from console is:

```
snap Object {
  "email": "Jojo@gmail.com",
  "fullname": "Jojo",
  "money": 0,
  "phone": "Dnndnd",
  "uid": "8um8zHvlEvYRYnDrpNXnY8Kcc4s1",
  "userName": "Jojor",
}
```

But when I then call `getData()`:

```
let check=  getData();
console.log("check",check)
```

the return value show me this:

```
check Promise {
  "_A": null,
  "_x": 0,
  "_y": 0,
  "_z": null,
}
```

how can I return the console value?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't combine `await` and `then`, unless you know exactly what you're doing.
2. Using `await` does not make the code synchronous. Rather it makes the block where you `use` await **asynchronous**, which is precisely why you have to mark it with `async`.

With these two in mind, the proper code is:

```
const getData=async()=> {
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
    const reference = get(child(dbRef, `users/${user.uid}`))
    
    const snapshot = await reference;
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log("snap",snapshot.val())
        return snapshot.val();
    }
    // TODO: what do you want to return when the snapshot doesn't exist?
}
```

And then:

```
let check= await getData();
         // 
console.log("check",check)
```

Or:

```
getData().then((check) => {
    console.log("check",check);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank, it works with this method ,but how can I use the return value outside of the arrow function?

Comment: The only way to do that is with `await` as shown in the example in my answer that does `let check= await getData()`. There is no way to make an asynchronous operation behave synchronously, so you'll always have to use `then` or `await` to wait for its completion.